# How can I show images like Windows Explorer does in a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx

Recently I have been trying to write a photo album by JavaFX, so I not only need to show pictures in a board but also I have to handle some selection events such as single selection by clicked and multiple selection using CTRL and click.

As shown in the image, I just used a "ListView" Class in JavaFX to implement it, which can handle selection event by using its existing methods.

However, when I want to achieve this interaction: drag mouse to draw a rectangle, pictures inside the rectangle are selected, and if click in blank, all the pictures selected will be set free(exactly these are operations in Windows Explorer), I have difficulty in tackling it. Before questioning this, I also read some examples about implementing multiple selection by mouse dragging in JavaFX, which only highlight the selected items. But except that, I still want to know which items are being selected(in this case, I want to know which images are selected) so that I can do copy, delete or something else.

That is to say, I indeed want to display and select my pictures like Windows Explorer does, is there any method to achieve this in JavaFX?

Thanks for your helping in advance!

[multiple selection by mouse dragging in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssc8n.png)

[my implementaion via ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp1Lw.png)

Comment: Draw a rectangle using upper-left and lower-right as the bounding box for the rectangle, and then each item whose position is within the bounding box are selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there are any implementation of rectangle selection in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763445/is-there-are-any-implementation-of-rectangle-selection-in-javafx)

Comment: AFAIK there is no control supporting layout in a grid and allowing for Perhaps you could adjust `GridView` from ControlsFX to suit your needs, but you need to implement the selection on your own. Also the last time I used that class it called `updateItem` incredibly often so make sure to cache the images...

Comment: @fabian Thanks. Yeah, I had tried to use GridView before, but failed. I was confused how can I know which items are selected? Could you give an example about doing this? Thank you!